# tableview visibleCells causes crash

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, crash

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tableView.visibleCells.forEach {
            if let cell = $0 as? PostsWithVideoCustom , let player = cell.player {
                player.pause()
                cell.player = nil
            }
        }
    }
```

I use this code on `viewDidDisappear` and it is ok normally.

However, if I `performSegue` on `viewWillAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if userDefaults.string(forKey: "goToEvent") != nil {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "postToEvent", sender: self)
        }
       }
```

I am having crash on line `tableView.visibleCells.forEach`

How can handle this crash and what may cause it?

UPDATE

This crash only happens if the app started after it gets killed, doesn't happen when waken from background

Crash

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  APP                        0x104521cd4 specialized Posts.viewDidDisappear(_:) (Posts.swift:2127)
1  APP                        0x104519864 @objc Posts.viewWillAppear(_:) + 4334082148
2  UIKitCore                      0x247561684 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 488
3  UIKitCore                      0x247562008 -[UIViewController __viewDidDisappear:] + 144
4  UIKitCore                      0x2474c31d8 -[UINavigationController viewDidDisappear:] + 232
5  UIKit                          0x23b4b5ea8 -[UINavigationControllerAccessibility viewDidDisappear:] + 40
6  UIKitCore                      0x247561684 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 488
7  UIKitCore                      0x247562008 -[UIViewController __viewDidDisappear:] + 144
8  UIKitCore                      0x247498890 -[UITabBarController viewDidDisappear:] + 100
9  UIKitCore                      0x247561684 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 488
10 UIKitCore                      0x247562008 -[UIViewController __viewDidDisappear:] + 144
11 UIKitCore                      0x247564168 __64-[UIViewController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:]_block_invoke.1383 + 44
12 UIKitCore                      0x247562764 -[UIViewController _executeAfterAppearanceBlock] + 88
13 UIKitCore                      0x247b10ef8 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 564
14 UIKitCore                      0x247aff93c _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 352
15 UIKitCore                      0x247b1e5a8 __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 136
16 CoreFoundation                 0x21b29ee68 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20
17 CoreFoundation                 0x21b29e76c __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 272
18 CoreFoundation                 0x21b2997d0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1024
19 CoreFoundation                 0x21b2990b0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
20 GraphicsServices               0x21d49979c GSEventRunModal + 104
21 UIKitCore                      0x247b05978 UIApplicationMain + 212
22 APP                        0x1044f8504 main (InboxInterests.swift:22)
23 libdyld.dylib                  0x21ad5e8e0 start + 4
```

Comment: post full crash ........

Comment: posted the full crash

Comment: sure that snippet is the reason of the crash meaning if you commented it will it still crashes or do you have a other content ?

Comment: Check if the `tableView` outlets is connected properly.

Comment: @Sh_Khan I am currently checking it, I will be updating the question upon the result

Comment: What if you add `super` calls at the beginning of both `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidDisappear` functions?

Comment: @AndréSlotta you think it will make a difference?

Comment: Might be. Worth a try.

Comment: This crash only happens if the app started after it gets killed, doesn't happen when waken from background

Comment: Which line exactly causes the crash? What is the full error message?

Comment: @Sh_Khan yeah it doesnt crash if I comment that line

Comment: @rmaddy tableView.visibleCells.forEach this line is crashing and you can find crash report in the question

Comment: I know the crash report is there. I asked what the error message was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by just adding

```
if tableView != nil {
        }
```

It was a very easy fix. But I think iOS should manage it itself in the first place.